# Constructor, Class, union, struct

Tags: c++, class, struct, unions

I have some doubts I would like to clear regarding class, struct and union. I know class and struct are considered object. I would like to check whether union is consider object too. Whereby, I can have a constructor inside?

```
union ABC
{
  ABC() {};
  int x;
}A, B, C
```

Since I have object name. I could do this?

```
Union ABC obj1(); //Call constructor?
A.x;  //Variable accessing the member
```

???
Secondly,
what if i typedef union. What does A B C mean?
Can I do this

```
union ABC obj1();
A.x;


typedef union ABC
{
  ABC() {};
  int x;
}A, B, C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The difference between a struct and a class is that by default
   members in struct are public, but private in class; otherwise, they
   are functional equivalent. A union can have member functions (including constructors   and destructors), but not virtual functions. A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class.
2. `Union ABC obj1(); //Call constructor?`

   No, This does not call a constructor

   `union ABC obj1()` means you
   declare a function with name `obj1` and returns an object of `union ABC`
3. You have syntax errors in both cases, you have to do the following:

   ```
   union ABC
   {
      ABC() {};
      int x;
    }A, B, C;   //You cannot miss this ;
   ```
4. You can do:

   ```
   typedef union ABC ABCUnion;   then 

    ABCUnion A, B,C;
   ```

   It is the same as

   ```
   union ABC A, B,C;
   ```